# How can I link a file in admin with a button?

Tags: permalinks, admin, buttons

Let suppose I have made a file in my theme folder (with the name c.php) and I want it to link it with a custom button (that I have made in post/page) in admin using GET action. How can I achieve that

Comment: You don't. Theme files should not be loaded directly. You won't have access to any of the WordPress environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I make it, the way without losing the access to WordPress environment:

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'custom_button' );
function custom_button() {
$button = sprintf('<a href="%1$s" class="button button-primary button-large">%2$s</a>', esc_url( add_query_arg( 'link' , true, get_the_permalink() ) ), 'Custom Button'
    );

    print_r($button);
}
```

**Update:**

***Hint***: Please make a function for validation the url for ssl and wrap get_the_permalink() inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Im a little unsure what you are trying to achieve but can't you link the button like:

```
href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/c.php"
```